Marklogic cts:search in RestApi extension
I do some cts:search when I PUT a document through a Rest API extension. This takes too long comparing to the same cts:search called in the GET method of the same extension.
Perhaps it is due to the update mode in a PUT call but I try to force the update mode to false
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <update>false</update>
</options>

but it does not solve the problem. Any ideas?

HTTP PUT calls to the REST API will be evaluated in update mode, which will
Use xdmp:invoke-function() and put your search inside of an anonymous function, so that it's evaluated outside of the update as a read-only query without locks:
https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function
xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
  cts:search(doc(), $query)
})

If you are trying to figure out whether or not it is acquiring locks, you can use xdmp:transaction-locks() inside of that function to report the locks for the transaction.
